# Get error when try read sms with at command

Tags: serial-port, sms, gsm, at-command

I'm trying to use AT command for send/read the sms with nokia 5530 serial port on com6

I can connect and send sms correctly without any error and recipient get the message.
But the problem: I can't read any message and get "Error" nothing more !!!! check the below image for more info:
[image]

What is the problem and how can I read the sms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the AT+CNMI command before the AT+CMGL. It tells the device what to do with incoming messages.

try:  AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0

Also, try this: AT+CMGL=?  to see if the command is supported by your device. It should respond "OK" if it is. If not, it isn't supported.

Comment: Thanks, my phone doesn't support it.